# How to insert pdf page in other pdf file in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I have one pdf file pdf1.pdf having 30 pages and other pdf file pdf2.pdf having 1 pdf page ,now I want to insert second pdf2.pdf in first pdf1.pdf in many places i.e between fifth and sixth page and also between 21 and 22 page .So How can I do it in laravel 5.5

Comment: Welcome to OS, please look at [How to Ask](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by normal means.